# Difference between Tabs Widget and navbar JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am confused between these two, not sure when to use what and what is the difference.

From https://api.jquerymobile.com/tabs/

```
<div data-role="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#fragment-1" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
```

From http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

```
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="a.html" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
</ul> </div>
```

Comment: From the name, navbar for navigation, changes pages. Tabs to show/hide contents within the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then why navbar inside tabs, without navibar tab list shows vertically.